# MySQL/PHP traer de la base de datos el id específico de un campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Buenas, tengo esta base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un **intervaloHorario** tiene muchas **citas**

**Citas** (idCitas, idIntervaloHorario, cita)

**IntervalosHorarios** (idIntervaloHorario, intervaloHorario)

En la tabla:

Necesito obtener el id del intervalo horario que está relacionado con su cita correspondiente.

El objetivo es obtener dinámicamente el id del intervalo dependiendo del id de la cita que se inserte, no sé si me explico.

[image: Tabla]

**Consulta en el modelo**

```
 public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {

      $query = $this->db->query('select intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario '
            . 'from intervaloshorarios left join citas '
            . 'on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario=citas.idCitas '
            . 'where citas.idCitas =  '.$idCarga.' ;');


        return $query ->result();
}
```

**Código del controlador**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    //$this->load->model('Entregas_Model');
    //$this->load->model('Entregas_Model');

    /* Para deseleccionar un botón mediante un método */
    /* Con esto no se podrá seguir pulsando el botón */
    if ($this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga)) {
        $crud->unset_add();
    }

    //$this->Entregas_Model->get_rowslimit($idCarga);
    //$this->Entregas_Model->get_ordercolumns();
    //$crud->unset_bootstrap();
    //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /
    $datos = array(
        'title' => "Solicitudes", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
        'username' => "Administrador"
    );

    $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

    //Quitamos los botones de añadir y quitar
    //$crud->unset_add();
    //$crud->unset_edit();
    //Limitando el número de filas
    //echo 'Reached limit';


    $crud->set_language("spanish");
    $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');

    $crud->set_table('entregas');
    //$crud->unset_columns(array('accion', 'estado'));

    $crud->display_as('idCitas', 'Cita');
    $crud->display_as('idAcciones', 'Acción');
    $crud->display_as('idEstadoSolicitud', 'Estado Solicitud')
            ->display_as('horaCita', 'Hora Cita')
            ->display_as('numeroEntrega', 'Nº Entrega')
            ->display_as('Origen', 'Orígen')
            ->display_as('cargaPrevista', 'Carga Prevista')
            ->display_as('entregaPrevista', 'Entrega Prevista');


    //Clausula where donde se filtra la consulta para obtener los 
    //vehículos de ese intervalo
    $crud->where('entregas.idCitas =', $idCarga);

    $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');

    //$crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
    //Relación con la tabla citas
    //$crud->set_relation('idCitas', 'citas', 'cita');
    //Relación con la tabla acciones
    $crud->set_relation('idAcciones', 'acciones', 'nombreAccion');
    //Relación con la tabla estado
    $crud->set_relation('idEstadoSolicitud', 'estadosolicitudes', 'nombreEstado');

    //callback before insert
    //$crud->add_fields('idCitas', 'idAcciones', 'idEstadoSolicitud', 'fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista');
    //$crud->edit_fields('idAcciones', 'idEstadoSolicitud', 'fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista');
    //Intento de autorrellenar un campo
    /* $query = $this->Entregas_Model->get_id();

      $crud->field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $query); */

    //Esta consulta es para obtener el id del intervalo y pasarlo por aquí
    $query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCarga);


    //!Solo hay que hacer la relación cuando haya que mostrar el campo de opción!
    //Esta sentencia es para pasar el campo oculto
    if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
        $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);


        $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);
    }

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);

    //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
    $this->load->view('commons/footer');
}

/* Esto es para que me lleve a la vista de alumnos
  public function _callback_webpage_url($nombreCurso, $row) {
  return "<a href='" . base_url('admin/sub_webpages/' . $row->idCurso) . "'>$nombreCurso</a>";
  } */

//Sin esta función, no se mostraría nada
function _example_output($output = null) {
    $this->load->view('example', (array) $output);
}
```

Con esta consulta no me da error pero tampoco me deja guardar el formulario, por lo que intuyo que la consulta está mal realizada. ¿Cómo puedo hacerla correctamente?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que realiza la consulta? ¿Usas PDO, mysqli o las las funciones mysql_*? ¿`$idCitas` es un entero o qué tipo de dato?

Comment: El código que realiza la consulta lo he puesto en la parte del modelo, sin funciones, he tratado de usar el sql más puro, $idCitas es un entero y lo que hago al llamar a la función es filtrar por este id, lo que quiero es que al filtar también me traiga sus intervalos correspondientes, pero no lo consigo.

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que `get_idintervalo()` devuelve una cadena de caracteres que contiene una sentencia SQL? Es decir, la función devuelve `SELECT ..` y no el resultado de realizar la consulta SQL. En ningún momento de ese código veo que realices la consulta SQL.

Comment: Pensaba que con esa consulta estaba comparando el id que tengo y el que necesito y así obtener el id del intervalo que está en la misma fila que la cita, la verdad es que no entiendo mucho sql y esa consulta la he adaptado de internet

Comment: La consulta más o menos está correcta (pero al no usar consultas preparadas podrías sufrir un ataque de inyección SQL), pero el problema es que nunca llegas a ejecutarla, sólo la defines.

Comment: te refieres a esto: $consulta->result(); ?

Comment: En tu valor devuelto `$consulta->result();` no existe. Sólo existe cuando se ejecuta una consulta y se quiere obtener de ella los resultados. Desearía pasar esto a un chat para discutir contigo cómo se usa una base de datos, pero aún no tienes la reputación mínima para poder chatear. El problema que sufres es bastante profundo ya que no distingues aún entre una cadena de caracteres y una consulta. Que una variable se llame `$consulta` no significa que su contenido sea una consulta (que, por cierto, el tipo exacto depende de si usas PDO, mysqli, etc).

Comment: Cierto, no me deja pasar esto al chat... tengo otra cuenta en la que sí me deja. Pues pensaba hasta ahora que el contenido de una consulta se pasaba a la variable y posteriormente se podía devolver en la función. He mirado mi archivo database.php y aparece esto: `dbdriver' => mysqli` con lo que intuyo que es mysqli.

Comment: Para empezar deberías activar la depuración: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html Y luego usa `$resultado = $this->db->query($consulta);`. Cuando se ejecute la consulta `$resultado` tendrá un resultado de la consulta que podrás analizar y ver su contenido. Como no sé cómo gestiona la vista codeigniter no sé cómo sacar los datos de esa consulta a tu vista, eso se lo dejaría a otra persona que supiera de este framework en particular.

Comment: He usado lo que me has propuesto, aún no he depurado pero utilizando tus líneas aparece este error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'citas.idCitas = 1' at line 1` lo cierto es que no sé qué es lo que ocurre ahora

Comment: Mira bien tu consulta SQL, no dejas espacio entre el where y la línea anterior;: `dIntervaloHorario=citas.idCitas"
                . "where citas.idCitas` debería ser: `dIntervaloHorario=citas.idCitas "
                . "where citas.idCitas`. Fíjate en el espacio después de `dIntervaloHorario=citas.idCitas`.

Comment: Me di cuenta, voy a actualizar la consulta para que se vea bien cómo está actualmente. Con lo que hay ahora mismo me tira el error del array to string...

Comment: Ahora mismo parece que ya estás obteniendo bien los datos, pero hay que usar `fetch` para obtener los registros (ninguno o varios). Necesito el código completo del controlador para decirte dónde debes hacer cada cosa.

Comment: @OscarGarcia acabo de subir el código completo del controlador, a ver si te sirve para poder echarme una mano

Comment: Lo siento, hasta mañana no podré seguir con este tema. He visto que has agregado bastante información. Está muy bien y ahora es más probable que otro compañero pueda ayudarte. Suerte!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y el de todos! Ojalá lo solucione y así todos nos podamos beneficiar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí está la solución:

[Solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166432/php-foreach-not-working-when-iterating-query-result?noredirect=1#comment75349516_44166432)

**Modelo**

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario FROM intervaloshorarios INNER JOIN citas '
                    . 'ON intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario '
                    . 'WHERE citas.idCitas = ' . $idCitas . ';');

            return $query->result();
```

**Controlador(ver foreach)**

```
$query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCitas);


        if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
//It's wroking fine getting this
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCitas);

foreach ($query as $key) {
            //Is not working fine (throws array to string conversion)
            $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $key);
        }
```

Comment: Me alegra que finalmente arreglaras tu problema. Recuerda poner en tu respuesta lo más relevante del enlace que proporcionas para que ésta pueda ser útil sin necesidad de visitar dicho enlace. Si lo haces nómbrame (con el @ delante) y te daré mi +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Igual me estoy confundiendo pero en la consulta, el left join no debería de ser 
                . "left join citas on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario=citas.**idIntervaloHorario**"

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! tienes razón debería ser así, aun así no me da el resultado esperado @Iraitz

Comment: Hola Jose, en una ratito me creo la estructura y compruebo a ver porque no sale va? esta tarde te doy una respuesta! Un saludo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte la molestia! La verdad que sigo sin poder darle solución a esto, bienvenido sea cualquier aporte :) @Iraitz

Comment: Disculpame @Jose , he tenido bastante lío, acabo unas cositas y le echo un ojo.

Comment: Vale mirando tu estructura de BD, por lo que veo la tabla CITAS la tienes relacionada con la tabla INTERVALOS, con una Foreign Key "idIntervaloHorarios" con lo cual, si tu haces una select a CITAS tienes el idIntervaloHorario con ella -> **SELECT * FROM Citas WHERE idCitas =  '.$idCarga.'** de ahí y con ese idIntervaloHorario haces otra query a IntervaloHorarios y sacas la info que quieras

Comment: O, para hacerlo todo en una sola query -> **SELECT * FROM IntervalosHorarios INNER JOIN Citas ON IntervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario = Citas.idIntervaloHorario WHERE Citas.idCitas = '.$idCita.'** _Fijate que en la función que has posteado, le estás pasando el parámetro **$idCitas** y en la query el estás pasanso **$idCarga**_

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta tarde voy a probarlo a ver que tal @Iraitz

Comment: Ya vamos progresando, aunque me trae el id del intervalo, éste siempre es 1 (estoy usando la función print_r($expression); para evitar el array to string conversion... Estoy usando la segunda solución que has propuesto.

Comment: P.D. He probado la consulta en phpmyadmin y va bien, es decir, que da el resultado esperado, no sé por qué aquí no.

Comment: Pues ahí ya me pillas, no entiendo como en phpmyadmin te puede devolver una cosa y en código otra...

Comment: Ya está resuelta la duda, era mucho más sencillo de lo que parecía, había que hacer un foreach en el controlador iterando el id. Subo la respuesta. Muchísimas gracias por todo.